# What kind of an animal is that?

Tags: species-identification, entomology

[image]

Found in Austria. At half past nine p.m. in the summer/autumn.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Due to the long legs and the shape of the abdomen, this is probably a [crane fly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crane_fly), a dipteran from the Family Tipulidae.

Just for comparisson, here is *Holorusia hespera*:

[image]

Crane flies can be very large. I still remember the first crane fly I saw, in New Zealand: it seemed like a humongous mosquito (mosquitoes are dipterans from a different family, called Culicidae), it was quite impressive. Have a look at the size of this crane fly:

[image]

Despite their scary size, do not fear them. Unlike mosquitoes, crane flies are completely harmless: adults have a short life span, only days (just enough to reproduce), and in most species of crane flies adults don't eat at all.

Regarding the exact species of your specimen: the number of species in Europe is huge and, together with the fact that your photo is not the best one, it will be very difficult narrowing this down to Species, or even to Genus. Therefore, a better photo is necessary.

Comment: That's more than enough information, thank you! :)